# Archive folders group by date in powershell V4

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to archive files in a path that are older than X number of day. I have a folder with a years worth of files and the end goal is to Archive items based on the moth. So i'll have a folder for each month.

```
$SourcePath = "C:\users\StackoverFlow\Downloads"

$maxdays ="-30"

$CurrentDate = Get-Date

$ArchiveDate = $CurrentDate.AddDays($maxdays)

$destination = "C:\users\StackoverFlow\Desktop\Downloads.Zip"

$groups = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | 
    Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $ArchiveDate) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false) } | 
    group {"'{0}\{1}\{2:D2}'" -f $_.CreationTime}

ForEach ($group in $groups) {
    ForEach($file in $group.Group){
       Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
     [io.compression.zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourcePath, $destination) 
    }
}
```

I was hoping that the RegEx would do this, but it doesn't seem to do anything..

Suggestions?

Comment: Your format string has 3 placeholders, but you provide only one argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group them by Month and Year, make sure your format string represents just those values.

The `-f` operator supports standard date time formatting, so you could do:

```
Group-Object {"{0:MMyyyy}" -f $_.CreationTime}
```

To zip the grouped files into individual archives, you'll have to moved them into individual folders first:

```
Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"

$SourcePath = "C:\users\StackoverFlow\Downloads"
$destination = "C:\users\StackoverFlow\Desktop\{0}"

$maxdays = -30
$CurrentDate = Get-Date

$ArchiveDate = $CurrentDate.AddDays($maxdays)

$groups = Get-ChildItem $SourcePath | 
    Where-Object { ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $ArchiveDate) -and ($_.psIsContainer -eq $false) } | 
    Group-Object { "{0:MMyyyy}" -f $_.CreationTime }

# Create a temporary working dir
$TmpDirPath = Join-Path $([System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()) $([System.IO.Path]::GetRandomFileName())
$TmpDirectory = New-Item -Path $TmpDirPath -ItemType Directory 

ForEach ($group in $groups) {
    # Create a new directory for the group
    $GroupDirectory = New-Item -Path (Join-Path $TmpDirectory.FullName -ChildPath $group.Name) -ItemType Directory
    # Move files into the new directory
    $group.Group | Move-Item -Destination $GroupDirectory.FullName

    # Create the month-specific archive
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($GroupDirectory.FullName, ($destination -f $group.Name)) 
}
```

This will create a Zip archive per month.
If you want it all in one zip file, move the `CreateFromDirectory` call outside the loop and target the top-level temporary directory we created:

```
$destination = "C:\users\StackoverFlow\Desktop\Downloads.zip"
# ...
foreach ($group in $groups) {
    # Create a new directory for the group
    $GroupDirectory = New-Item -Path (Join-Path $TmpDirectory.FullName -ChildPath $group.Name) -ItemType Directory
    # Move files into the new directory
    $group.Group | Move-Item -Destination $GroupDirectory.FullName

}
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($TmpDirectory.FullName, $destination)
```

Comment: Thanks, even after changing that, all it seems to be doing it putting every item in the zip folder regardless of date. Ideally I want folders like this
012016
022016
032016

Comment: @JonnyBoy Sorry, didn't even notice the last half. You'll need to move the files into a temporary folder, then zip that individually. I'll update my answer

Comment: you sir are fantastic. I am running into some issues running it though.. :(  it doesn't seem to like the Tmp Path.. I'm sure it's just me being dumb but it is throwing out quite a few errors..First one.......At line:17 char:17
+ $TmpDirectory = New-Item -Path $TmpDirPath -ItemType Directory
second........At line:21 char:49
+ ... pDirectory = New-Item -Path (Join-Path $TmpDirectory.FullName -ChildP ...  third is destination is null and fourth is create directory is not a legal form.. I really appreciate all your help here !

Comment: What is the actual error message from the first error (on creating the `$TmpDirectory`?). Also, what version of PowerShell is this?

Comment: New-Item : The given path's format is not supported.
At line:17 char:17
+ $TmpDirectory = New-Item -Path $TmpDirPath -ItemType Directory
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand...............This is testing on Powershell v5... But it will be ran on V4 ... I can create a test on V4 if it makes a difference.

Comment: My bad, was using `GetTempFileName()` instead of `GetRandomFileName()` to generate the tmp directory name, fixed now

Comment: AWESOME! i added .Zip to the destination path without having that it seemed to create a file that couldn't be unzipped. Either way, this is exactly what I needed. You are a god, i appreciate this more than you know.